# setState callback method equivalent for useState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm looking for running some code after I set a new state via the "useState" hook. The only method I found tho was using "useEffect". But when i understand correctly, that would mean that code would run every time when I change the state. What if I have something like:

```
function example(props){
   const [example,setExample]=useState("")
   return[
      <div>{example}</div>,
      <Button onClick={()=>{setExample("Exampletext")}}>Set Text to Exampletext</Button>,
      <Button onClick={()=>{setExample("Exampletext",
            ()=>{
                   sleep(5000);//pseudo Code for "wait 5 seconds"
                   setExample("")}
             )}}>
       Set Text to Exampletext and back</Button>
   ]
}
```

(how I would write it if useState had a callback)
In this example, I can't use useEffect, since it would make both buttons behave the same if I'm not mistaken.

**Edit:**
I thought a general Example would suffice, but since there seems to be a solution to the example that doesn't apply to my problem, let me explain my case:

```
const [abortController, setAbortController] = React.useState(new Abortcontroller());

    const handleGetDetail = () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        setIsError(false);
        abortController.abort();
        setAbortController(new AbortController());
        axios
            .get(`../../api/rest/${parameters.endpoint}/${parameters.pk}/`, {
                signal: abortController.signal,
                headers: { Accept: "application/json" },
            })
            .then((results) => {
                setFormData(results.data);
                setIsLoading(false);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                if (error.name !== "CanceledError") {
                    console.log(error);
                    setIsError(true);
                    setIsLoading(false);
                }
            });
    };
```

The axios request starts before a new AbortController is initialized, so it will start with an already aborted signal and won't work at all. And i can't use **useEffect** , cause i am reusing the same abort controller for all requests of that component (there is an analoge method for **post** and **patch** ....).
The point of that code should be, to cancel the last request, if the user sends a second one before the first one is finished.

Comment: Let me get this straight: you want the second button to set the state on click and then automatically reset it after 5 seconds?

Comment: Yes,  was the first example i could think of. Should be just an example when useEffect isn't solving the problem.

Comment: I fixed it now with ```abortController.abort(); abortController=new AbortController()```. I mean, the documentation says to never set a state directly without the set-method... but thats the best i came up with for now

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `useState` does not have a callback like `setState` of the class-based component.

But we still can use `setTimeout` for waiting time which will help you to delay the 2nd `setState` with a pre-defined time period.

```
function example(props) {
  const [example, setExample] = useState("");
  return [
    <div>{example}</div>,
    <Button
      onClick={() => {
        setExample("Exampletext");
      }}
    >
      Set Text to Exampletext
    </Button>,
    <Button
      onClick={() => {
        setExample("Exampletext");
        setTimeout(() => {
          setExample("");
        }, 5000); //will be triggered after 5 seconds
      }}
    >
      Set Text to Exampletext and back
    </Button>,
  ];
}
```

Comment: well, would that one break if you set it to something more computational demanding than a string? If it would **setExample(exampleFunction(10000))**, and exampleFunction would take longer than 5 seconds, ill end up with the wrong state, wouldnt i?

Comment: Ideally, the state update is usually less than a second. If you have a complex computation, you should process data before calling `setExample`. For example, `const processedExample = exampleFunction(10000); setExample(processedExample);`. You should let state update do a single job only instead of carrying a lot of stuff along with it. @Zergoholic